# Updating Mongoid document in Rails 4 rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, rake

This code seemed to work fine until I upgraded to Rails 4:

```
desc "import the books"
task books: :environment do
  records = JSON.parse(File.read('app/data/books.json'))
  records.each do |record|
    book = Book.find_or_create_by(:link => record["link"])
    record.each do |k, v|
      if book.send(k).blank?
        book.send(k+"=", v)
      else
        unless v.blank?
          book.send(k+"=", v)
        end
      end
    end
    book.save
  end
end
```

But now when I attempt to import this, all the values (except for :link, which was specified in the find_or_create_by method) are nil.

```
#<Course _id: 53a07c1f4d61630d34980200, name: nil, language: nil, image: nil, link: "example.com", affiliate_link: nil>
```

Is this caused by some kind of protection against mass assignment that was implemented in Rails 4? I didn't realize that might affect Rake tasks. How can I best get around this. Thanks for your fast help!

Answer (score 0):

find_or_create_by isn't working for some reason, so I implemented the following workaround:

```
book = Book.where(:link => record["link"]).first
if book.blank?
  book = Book.create!
end
```

This seems to have the exact same effect, but actually works in Rails 4 / Mongoid 4.0.0.beta1